# How transform row values to a single string in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with variable group and want to create a string/or dt which shows the output of column group2 (comma / or space separated). How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: `paste0(df$group, collapse = ' ')`

Comment: thanks, it is working